# Using wmemset in c++

Tags: c++, string

While using wmemset api (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fdeehz6(VS.80).aspx) for the count parameter should I have to multiply the length of the target string by 2 and provide or will wmemset will itself take care of the conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no.  They have an example on [the page you linked to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fdeehz6%28VS.80%29.aspx):

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    wchar_t buffer[] = L"This is a test of the wmemset function";

    wprintf( L"Before: %s\n", buffer );
    wmemset( buffer, '*', 4 );
    wprintf( L"After:  %s\n", buffer );
}
```

Output:

```
Before: This is a test of the wmemset function
After:  **** is a test of the wmemset function
```

Of course, the destination must have enough space (`sizeof(wchar_t)` times the number of characters being written to).

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not. Length is in string characters (`wchar_t`), not in bytes (`char`). You need to pass the number of wide characters.